# How to use embedding layer and other feature columns together in a network using tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let’s consider a example data set contains 6 columns and 10 rows.

In these 3 columns are numeric and remaining 3 columns are categorical variable.

categorical columns are converted into multi hot encoded array of size 10x3.

I have target columns which i want predict is also categorical variable which can take 3 possible values again. This column is one hot encoded.

Now I want to use this multi-hot-encoded array as input to embedding layer. Embedding layer should output 2 units.

Then I want to use 3 numeric columns from the dataset and 2 output units from the embedding layer total 5 unit as input to the hidden layer.

This is the place I got stuck up. I don’t know how to bridge embedding layer and my other feature columns using tensorflow keras, also I don’t know how to pass input for embedding layer and other 2 units.

I have googled it. I tried the following code but still I get error. 
**I guess there is no Merge layer in tf.keras package**.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        import tensorflow as tf
        from tensorflow import keras
        import numpy as np

        num_data = np.random.random(size=(10,3))
        multi_hot_encode_data = np.random.randint(0,2, 30).reshape(10,3)
        target =  np.eye(3)[np.random.randint(0,3, 10)]

        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=multi_hot_encode_data.shape[1], output_dim=2))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(num_data.shape[1],)))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

        model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.01),
                      loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                      metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])

        #model.fit([multi_hot_encode_data, num_data], target)   # I get error here
```

My network structure will be

```
    multi-hot-encode-input  num_data_input 
            |                   |
            |                   |
            |                   |
        embedding_layer         |
            |                   |
            |                   | 
             \                 /        
               \              / 
              dense_hidden_layer
                     | 
                     | 
                  output_layer
```

Comment: Did you try concatenating them?

Comment: @PMende Hi.. not sure how concatenate works. but I tried  i again got invalid syntax error. Can please through an example here.

Comment: Does anybody know how to use tf.keras.Concatenate for the above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "merge" pattern incompatible with a sequential model. I think it's easier to use functional keras API with [`keras.Model`](https://keras.io/models/model/) instead of `keras.Sequential` ([short explanation of main differences](https://jovianlin.io/keras-models-sequential-vs-functional/)):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

num_data = np.random.random(size=(10,3))
multi_hot_encode_data = np.random.randint(0,2, 30).reshape(10,3)
target =  np.eye(3)[np.random.randint(0,3, 10)]

# Use Input layers, specify input shape (dimensions except first)
inp_multi_hot = keras.layers.Input(shape=(multi_hot_encode_data.shape[1],))
inp_num_data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(num_data.shape[1],))
# Bind nulti_hot to embedding layer
emb = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=multi_hot_encode_data.shape[1], output_dim=2)(inp_multi_hot)  
# Also you need flatten embedded output of shape (?,3,2) to (?, 6) -
# otherwise it's not possible to concatenate it with inp_num_data
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb)
# Concatenate two layers
conc = keras.layers.Concatenate()([flatten, inp_num_data])
dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu, )(conc)
# Creating output layer
out = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(dense1)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp_multi_hot, inp_num_data], outputs=out)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.01),
              loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
```

- You shold either flatten output of embedding layer before concatenate it, or numeric_data should have compatible shape and at least three dimensions
- define Functional model after layers. Inputs and outputs may be a single layer or an iterable of layers

Output of `model.summary`:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 3)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)         (None, 3, 2)         6           input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 6)            0           embedding_2[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_6 (InputLayer)            (None, 3)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 9)            0           flatten[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 3)            30          concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 3)            12          dense[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 48
Trainable params: 48
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Also, it fits successfuly:

```
model.fit([multi_hot_encode_data, num_data], target)
Epoch 1/1
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 1.0623 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3000
```

Comment: I think the line 
"inp_num_data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(multi_hot_encode_data.shape[1],))"
should be write as 
"inp_num_data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(num_data.shape[1],))"
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @shakthydoss exactly, my bad. Fixed!

Comment: My embedding layer is using mask_zero , I can not use Flatten layer on the embedding layer with mask though